# NGINX, The requested resource is not found

Tags: nginx

I am trying to start NGINX on port 80, first the I got this `This localhost page can’t be found` when go to http://localhost. I disabled the World Wide Web Publishing Service. Now gets this error

[image]

How make NGINX work?
I use Windows 10 and the default conf of NGINX